# how to go previous page in asp.net after clicking previous button in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net

Hi
I have one label for question, radiobuttonlist for their answers, next button to move next question & previous button. I am displaying one question per page after clicking next button next question appears, but when i click previous button previous question should be display. How i can go to previous question to change answer.

Asp.net c#
Thank you.

Comment: This is code you have to write manually, there's no magic code that "display previous question". If you'll post your existing code and explain how it works and where it fails we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

One work around is to use History.Back function of Javascript...

```
onclick="javascript:History.Back();"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your task is best solved by using [asp:Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163894.aspx) control. May be you'll want to refer to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdb4eb30.aspx) or to a simple [tutorial](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/060706.htm).